# Multiple where clause on same column

Tags: mysql, join, union, where-clause

Hi I have finally figured out how to get the results in single rows, but am stuck with getting the correct results.

Below is my query. I am trying to get the COUNT of faults reported and faults completed for a month. When I change the dateFormat(date_reported to dateFormat(date_completed the numbers change, alternating from reported to completed.

```
select
    count(r.rpt) as Reported,
    count(c.cpt) as Completed, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_REPORTED,'%M %Y') as MONTH

from
    (select COUNT(faultid) as cpt
     from fault_info 
     where status = 'Completed'
     and date_completed >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY
     ) c,
    (select COUNT(faultid) as rpt
     from fault_info 
     where status != 'Completed'
     and date_reported >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY
     ) r,
    fault_info

GROUP BY MONTH

ORDER BY date_reported desc
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

This is the output I am after. But at the moment I simply get the same number for both columns. As stated above, to change the number I change the DateFormat(date_reported -> DateFormat(date_completed, but the numbers still stay the same. They are correct for one but not the other.

Select DateFormat(date_reported...

Reported, Completed, MONTH

'99', '99', 'January 2014'

'72', '72', 'December 2013'

'71', '71', 'November 2013'

'107', '107', 'October 2013'

'114', '114', 'September 2013'

'112', '112', 'August 2013'

OR Select DateFormat(date_completed...

Reported, Completed, MONTH

'68', '68', 'January 2014'

'65', '65', 'December 2013'

'76', '76', 'November 2013'

'113', '113', 'October 2013'

'124', '124', 'September 2013'

'140', '140', 'August 2013'

This way I can do a percentage comparison I can see if we are closing more faults that we open. So I need the actual reported for a month vs the actual closed for a month.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 2):

Slightly restructured, you should be able to do in a single pass vs multiple

```
SELECT
      DATE_FORMAT(DATE_REPORTED,'%M %Y') as MONTH,
      SUM( status = 'Completed' ) as Completed,
      SUM( status != 'Completed' ) as StillOpen
   from
      fault_info
   group by
      DATE_FORMAT(DATE_REPORTED,'%M %Y'),
   order by
      YEAR( DATE_REPORTED ) desc,
      MONTH( DATE_REPORTED ) desc
```

the sum of a logical expression (such as status = 'Completed' ) when true will equal 1, else 0.  So, querying through the rows you are getting both possible counts with single group by aggregation and still order them in descending date (year/month) basis for most recent at the top going down through historical values.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its not quite what I'm after. Please see my edit and if you can help that would be awesome!!